# Prevent "over-reporting" due to SQL LEFT JOIN row duplication

Tags: sql, t-sql, left-join

I have a query with a bunch of LEFT JOINs that result in duplication of the LEFT rows.
This, of course, is expected. But what I can't figure out is how to blank a column on repeating records to avoid incorrect totals.

For example, lets say we have a Warehouse Receipt for an item which then gets sold to multiple Customers:

| Receipt No | Receipt Quantity | Shipment No | Shipment Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R123 | 1,000 | S1 | 100 |
| R123 | 1,000 | S2 | 700 |
| R123 | 1,000 | S3 | 200 |

If we total the numbers, it would look like we received 3,000 and shipped 1,000.

The output I would want to see is this:

| Receipt No | Receipt Quantity | Shipment No | Shipment Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R123 | 1,000 | S1 | 100 |
| R123 |  | S2 | 700 |
| R123 |  | S3 | 200 |

Now the totals would make sense.

Is this possible to do in the SQL JOIN somehow?

Comment: Group by the receipt number

Comment: An aggregation like `Max([Receipt Quantity]) , Sum([Shipment Quantity])`  would make sense too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select receipt_num,
       (case when 1 = row_number() over (partition by receipt_num order by shipment_num)
             then receipt_quantity
        end) as receipt_quantity
from . . .
order by receipt_num, shipment_num;
```